# Async and scheduling - how do libraries avoid blocking at the lowest level?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking, fibers, green-threads

I've been using various concurrency constructs for a while now without much consideration for how all the magic happens, which has recently made me increasingly uneasy.

In an attempt to remedy this ... feeling, I have been reading up on how async works under the hood. When I say async, in this case I'm referring to userland / greenthread / cooperative multitasking, although I assume some of the concepts will also apply to traditional OS managed threads insofar as a scheduler and workers are involved.

I see how a worker can suspend itself and let other workers execute, but at the lowest level in non-blocking library code, **how does the scheduler know when a previously suspended worker's job is done and to wake up that worker?**

- For example if you fire up a worker in some sort of async block and perform an operation that would normally block (e.g. HTTP request, SQL query, other I/O), then even though your calling code is async, that operation (library code) better play nice with your async framework or you've effectively defeated the purpose of using it and blocked your scheduler from calling other waiting operations (the, [What Color is Your Function](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) problem) while it waits for your blocking call, which was executed inside your non-blocking calling code, to complete.
- So now we've got async code calling other async library code, and now I'm asking myself the question all over again - **how does the async library code know when to suspend and resume operation?**

The idea of firing off a HTTP request, moving on, and returning later to check for results is weird to think about for me - not conceptually but from an implementation standpoint.

**How do you perform a partial operation, e.g. sending TCP packets and then continuing with the rest of the program execution, only to come back later and check if results have been delivered. Delivered to what? A socket?**

Now we're another layer deep and you are using socket selects to avoid creating threads and blocking, but, again...

- how do those sockets start an operation, move on before completion, and then how does select know when data is available?
- Are you continually checking some buffer to see if bytes have been delivered in an infinite loop and moving on if not?

Anyhow - I think you see where I'm going here....

I focused mainly on HTTP as a motivating example, but the same question applies for any normally blocking operations - **how does it all work at the bottom?**

Here are some of the resources I found helpful while researching the topic and which informed this question:

- David Beazley's excellent video [Build Your Own Async](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4Gt3Xjd7G8) where he walks you through a simple implementation of a scheduler which fire callbacks and suspend execution by sleeping on a waiting queue. I found this video tremendously instructive, but it stops a bit short in that it shows you how using an async sleep frees up the scheduler to execute other workers, but doesn't really go into what would happen when you call code in those workers that itself must be non-blocking so it plays nice with the scheduler.
- [How does non-blocking IO work under the hood](https://medium.com/ing-blog/how-does-non-blocking-io-work-under-the-hood-6299d2953c74) - This got me further along in my understanding, but still left with a few uncertainties.

Comment: I see a vote to close - is there something I should change about the question to make it more appropriate?

Comment: Have a look around about how Go schedules goroutines.  The available docs cover your questions quite well.